# Hide an element from another component

Tags: angular

In my component I have a property.

```
this.currentSection = section;
```

If the value of it is `green`, I would like to hide an element (`.my-class`), which is from another component.

How can I do this?

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9bsbj) (Component A should hide the class `.my-class` from component B)

Comment: we need more informations, where is the first componnent and the second componnent, to know the how we can bind it ? (i'm not doing any vote)

Comment: @Saad please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b9bsbj ... I hope that it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In component A you need @ViewChild() decorator.

```
 @ViewChild(ComponentB) refCmpB;
```

Then based on the value in component A, check condition and pass it to component B.

```
if (this.currentSelection === true) { 
    this.refCmpB.myClassProp = false;
}
```

In component B, in template file use this..

```
<h1 [ ngClass ] = " myClassProp === true ? 'my-class- 
 show' : ' my-class-hide ' "> show / hide </h1>
```

ngClass here selects .css class based on given condition.

Comment: Could you please show me an example of it on Stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-77wzbp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fb%2Fb.component.ts  checkout this stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

One of the fastest way to solve this, use [Behaviorsubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) and with Inputs send value of currentSection to nested components. [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-84xovd?file=src/app/a/a.component.ts) 
I added setTimeout to verify that this works.(in a.component.ts).

Also, you can check this framework, maybe will be helpful: [NgRx](https://ngrx.io/docs)

Comment: It was kind of hard for me to understand how it exactly works but it's still very interesting. Thank you for this answer!